# What is the difference between two functions

Tags: javascript, jquery

What is the difference between these two, I've seen developers using either of these :

this one:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    console.log("on load");
  });
```

and this one:

```
(function() {
    console.log("self properling");
  })();
```

What is the advantage of one over another if any?

Comment: One is a trigger when the DOM is ready, the other is a self invoking function.

Comment: And the duplicate is false. There's no `$`!

Comment: The answer voted as a duplicate is not the same as this one. Note the second example is a self-invoking function, NOT the jquery DOM ready shorthand `(function() { /* ... */ });`

Comment: @deceze Good eyes there. Voted to reopen.

Comment: The OP more than likely meant `$(function(){ //Shorthand });`

Comment: @Mark: You think they forgot the `$` and added `()` by mistake? Seems unlikely to me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a difference

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    console.log("on load");
  });
```

Will execute once the dom is ready

```
(function() {
    console.log("self properling");
  })();
```

is a self executing annonymous function, it will not wait for dom ready event

Comment: I think a better term to describe the second case is Immediately Invoked Function Expression - cf. http://benalman.com/news/2010/11/immediately-invoked-function-expression/

Comment: Who downvoted this? It's entirely correct.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I've learned to ignore those crazy down voters

Answer (score 4):

**DOM ready**: <sup>*Document is read and ready to be operated (P.S. Uncached Images are still being loaded)*</sup>

```
$(document).ready(function(){

});
```

**DOM ready shorthand**:

```
$(function(){

});
```

**Secure `jQuery` alias (`$`) DOM ready shorthand**: <sup>*Prevents conflict of `$` alias with other scripts*</sup>

```
jQuery(function( $ ){

});
```

**Secure `jQuery` alias (`$`) + self invoked (DOM not ready)**:

```
(function( $ ){

})( jQuery );
```

**Immediately Invoked Function Expression**:

```
(function myName(){

})();
```

**Named Function Declaration**:

```
function myName(){

}
```

**Anonymous Function stored in variable**:

```
var myName = function(){

};
```

**Named Function stored in variable**:

```
var myName = function myFun(){

};
```

Comment: You have to be a but careful: The second example in *"Immediately Self Invoked Function (Anonymous)"* is invalid JavaScript by itself. It is evaluated as function declarations and those must have names. Your *"Named function (stored in variable)"* example is actually an anonymous function stored in a variable. Named functions are always of the form `function name(){...}`. Function *declarations* are always named whereas function *expressions* can either be anonymous or named.